Are there any differences between different uefi vendors/implementations
I was wondering if there are any differences between the different uefi implementations of AMI, Insyde H2O and Phoenix. I've tried searching it online, but I couldn't find any other explanation than "they are almost the same".
One difference i notice on my desktop with AMI and my laptop with Insyde H20 is that it looks like the AMI uefi has more options and has a graphical interface while Insyde doesn't, but this may be because Acer has a very locked down uefi.

UEFI has a specification.  The interface will certainly be different to interact with that specification.

OEMs have often/always chosen which options to enable/present in their pre-boot environments. This is normal. It is particularly common that laptop devices have fewer presented options than desktop devices.
